# How to search for a particular matching property value inside an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I want to search only in `name` property of the list of json objects. This is the json array -

```
combinedArr = [
  {
    lat: "36.1152",
    locality: "Worth Avenue, Unit A",
    long: "117.521",
    name: "Bazaar Cafe",
    postal_code: "20619",
    street_no: "45250",
  },
  {
    lat: "31.21",
    locality: "Ambey Mantion",
    long: "119.7",
    name: "Ashley's Cafe",
    postal_code: "29087",
    street_no: "1B",
  },
];
```

This is the search function , this search function search in all properties of the objects but I just want it to search only in `name` property and return list of search results. The search function is the following -

```
  function findCaliforniaCafes(searchTerm) {
    const filterByValue = (combinedArr, string) => {
      return combinedArr.filter((o) =>
        Object.keys(o).some((k) =>
          o[k].toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase())
        )
      );
    };

    const result = searchTerm
      ? filterByValue(combinedArr, searchTerm)
      : combinedArr;

    return result;
  }
```

Comment: If you want to search only in the name, why are you iterating over all object keys? Just check `o.name` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `filter` like so:

```
const filtered = combinedArr.filter(({ name }) => name.includes("Ashley"));
```

```js
const combinedArr = [{lat:"36.1152",locality:"Worth Avenue, Unit A",long:"117.521",name:"Bazaar Cafe",postal_code:"20619",street_no:"45250",},{lat:"31.21",locality:"Ambey Mantion",long:"119.7",name:"Ashley's Cafe",postal_code:"29087",street_no:"1B",}];
const filtered = combinedArr.filter(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm));

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: `const filtered = combinedArr.filter(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm));`  a bracket is missing! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use array `filter()`.

This will return an array containing all elements that pass the condition.

```
const searchFilter = "Bazaar Cafe"


const filtered = combinedArr.filter(item => item.name === searchFilter);
```

Comment: Use `includes()` rather than `===`.